# Passing by reference and by value

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

We have functions

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x;
}
int bar(int& x)
{
    return x;
}
...
foo(5);//ok
bar(5);//error
```

I dont understand, what occur when we'r calling `foo(5)`? There is just allocated 4 bytes in memory and transmitted to `foo`? Or after allocating 4 bytes will be created copy of this memory cells and transmitted to `foo`?

Comment: The question and code seem to be referring to two separate things.
The answer for the question is that the 4 bytes allocation has been done at compile time. When you call the function the value of the argument to foo is copied into it when it is called.
The problem with code has already been explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function bar takes input parameters as references. The limitation for such a use is that you cannot pass literals as arguments while calling the function.

5 is a literal. You cannot pass a literal or an expression as a reference. Moreover, both your functions return integers but you are not catching them.

Function foo takes input by value. Hence a copy of the input variable is made and processed. The variable inside the function and calling variable outside are 2 different variables here.

More information can be seen at http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand you. Why we cant pass constants as reference, but non constant can pass?

Comment: @Dmitrii Check out the link I have mentioned. It should clarify your doubts.

Comment: I realize that literal is non refered value, but actually memory is allocated for this. We declare `const int z=5; foo(z)` and crashed. I have two doubts: Does we have copy of literal's value after passing this literal by value. Is every const just literal?

Comment: @Dmitrii A literal like '5' does not have an address in memory. It is dealt with the compiler directly. When you pass it as a parameter to a function (by value), a variable is created inside the function with value initialized to 5. const is not a literal as such. It is a special variable whose value cannot be changed, but it can be used like other variables throughout the program.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from information given in the other answer, I suggest googling things `lvalue` and `rvalue`.

Besides, imagine this worked:

```
void bar(int& x)
{
  x = 6; // modify the referenced value, not some local variable!
}

main() {
  int y = 6;
  bar(5);

  printf ("equal or not: %s\n", (y==6?"yes":"no"));
}
```

What should be the effect of running this program?